Mysql : how to join 2 row different colum using same table?
I try to get output from 2 row in single row for attendance report, but i dont know how. please help me
Table : attendance



no
id
punch_in
punch_out




1
1
2024-10-04 08:00



2
2
2024-10-05 08:10



3
2

2024-10-04 17:00


4
1

2024-10-05 17:30


5
2
2024-10-04 08:00



6
1
2024-10-05 08:10



7
2

2024-10-04 17:00


8
1

2024-10-05 17:30



output:



no
id
punch_in
punch_out




1
1
2024-10-04 08:00
2024-10-05 17:30


2
2
2024-10-05 08:10
2024-10-04 17:00


5
2
2024-10-04 08:00
2024-10-04 17:00


6
1
2024-10-05 08:10
2024-10-05 17:30




This is not an easy problem and it cannot be solved by single query in MySQL-5.7 without CTEs and window functions.
We can make a reasonable assumption that in and out events for certain id are interleaved regularly in time. Lets group event into pairs using UDVs:
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_attendance;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_attendance
SELECT a.no
     , a.id
     , @ordered_id := (@ordered_id + 1) AS ord_id  -- increment of UDV
     , a.punch_in
     , a.punch_out
  FROM attendance AS a
 WHERE ( @ordered_id := 0 ) <> 1 -- User defined variable initialization
 ORDER BY a.id ASC
        , a.no ASC
;

And now we can make a selfjoin:
SELECT a.no
     , a.id
     , a.punch_in
     , b.punch_out
  FROM temp_attendance AS a
  JOIN temp_attendance AS b ON a.id = b.id
                           AND a.ord_id = b.ord_id - 1
 WHERE a.punch_in IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY a.no ASC
;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_attendance;

Here empty fields in the table attendance are supposed to be NULL.

Caution:  The use of assigning user variables in a SELECT is deprecated and likely to be disallowed in the near future.

@RickJames OMG, why? Is there any link to the related info?

Syntax such as SELECT @var, @var:=@var+1 is still accepted in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility, but is subject to removal in a future MySQL version. (WL #12131) -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html
